# How to call a function from javascript file and save the return value as global

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Inside an `HTML` I have a script:

`<script src="info.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Inside `info.js` there is a function, lets say `getInfo(key)` which returns `info`.

How can I call a function located inside `info.js` from my html, so that I can use this variable inside the whole html document?

*[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) does not explain how to do this*

Comment: w3schools isn't really a great source for learning JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you understand what's going on.

Let's say the code below is located inside `info.js`

```
function getSomething(){
  return "something";
}
```

Now your HTML might look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="info.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <span id="mySpan"></span>

    <script>
        var myText = getSomething();

        $('#mySpan').text(myText); //this uses jQuery so you'll need to include that
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's the exact explanation I was looking for. I was finding it difficult to understand where do I put all these scripts and where to call the function from.

Comment: @FilipLuch You're welcome. This website might be beneficial to you: http://www.webdesigndegreecenter.org/learn-to-code/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var global; // global var

// js code...


// function
function myFunc(){
  global = getInfo(key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you correctly, that you want to use that info in all your html file, here's my answer. Let me know if it helps or if you meant anything else, I'll think accordingly.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="info.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var info = getInfo(key);
            $('div.myinfo').html(info);
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <div class="myinfo"></div>
</html>
```

You have the desired information in a javascript var and you can assign it as value to a input/select element or copy it as html to a div/td/p/h1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it like this:

```
var info = getInfo(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your calling script follows the method in info.js (and assuming the function is not private) it should be accessible in any script